# Unprotected connection to HTTPS web-page

Tags: ssl, browser, https, mixed-content

A couple of days ago we noticed that when we go to our online banking login page (using Opera browser as usual) there is no green lock icon there anymore. Instead, there is a grey globe icon which states "unprotected connection" even though it is an HTTPS page.[image]

We also tried using Chrome - same problem. We have checked this problem on two different machines (Windows 7, Windows 8, Ubuntu and mac). Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be and how we could fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: So its your site?  Something in the page is requesting a resource via HTTP instead of HTTPS, that's what needs to be addressed.